# install heroku-toolbelt in vagrant ubuntu precise32

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, vagrant

Hi im trying to install heroku-toolbelt in my Ubuntu virtual machine, i tryed

`wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

but nothing happended, No message was displayed.
So i got the script from the browser and started executing it line by line, but i got the following error:

> --2015-03-07 21:28:18--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... failed:
>   Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve host
>   address `toolbelt.heroku.com' gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by just doing:
 `vagrant halt`
and then 
`vagrant up` again. for some reason after reboot

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | she
```

was working